# Error parsing JSON responce object

Tags: java, android, json

I know this question has been asked 100 times, however i cant work out the following

I have a web service for login which responds with a JSON formatted string which looks like this

```
{
    "success": 0,
    "error_message": "Username and/or password is invalid."
}
```

which I know is a JSON object

I attempt to retrieve the object like so

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String TAG_PATH = "success";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String AuthResult2 = "";

    //this is where you should write your authentication code
    // or call external service
    // following try-catch just simulates network access
try{
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", emailTextView.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordTextView.getText().toString()));

    jParser.nameValuePairs = nameValuePairs;

    // Getting JSON from URL

    String url = "login.php";

    // JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        AuthResult2 = c.getString(TAG_PATH);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (AuthResult2.equals("true")) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

as you can see i have changed the line

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

to

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

I know I also have to remove the for...loop however im getting an error within Android Studio.

It says

> Required JSONObject Found JSONArray.

To my knowledge my code is sound.

Please Help i need to move on with my life

UPDATE
Copy of the error

```
C:\Users\Alex\AndroidStudioProjects\CameraScan4\app\src\main\java\com\example\alex\camerascan4\LoginActivity.java
Error:(295, 53) error: incompatible types
required: JSONObject
found:    JSONArray
Error:(300, 34) error: method getJSONObject in class JSONObject cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: int
reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
```

UPDATE

Here is my JSONParser, i completely forgot it relied on this, and assumed that it was a built in thing. How stupid do i feel. I see the reason the the type miss match, however i now can find a way to use 1 parser class to return either an array or an object depending on the response , not even sure thats possible. I then considered duplicating the class, 1 for array response and the other for object. But there must be a better way

I suppose i could turn the object (if thats what it receives) into an array and pass it back as normal???

Comment: Can you please post the error log and also specify the exact line that is causing the error? Also, what is `JSONParser`? Is that a custom class or a library you are using?

Comment: ive added them the the question able. cheers

Comment: What line is throwing the error? In the error it's mentioning the for() loop. Have you tried removing that part yet as you said?

Comment: Your error is in `LoginActivity.java`, but you've only show half of an AsyncTask. Please create a [mcve] for all the code that is having a problem.

Comment: I think the problem is in return type of `JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url)` You should show us your JSONParser